# How to run success function with JQuery getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I want to push data to an array, but am unsure how to go about this due to AJAX's asychronisity.

I can't seem to find complete examples online of the way this is done with getJSON.

I've been following the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) with no luck/

I have tried:

```
var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + addressval;
var latlng;

$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
  var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
  var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

  latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

}).done(function() {
  markerlocations.push(latlng);
})//END JSON
```

and:

var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + addressval;
    var latlng;

```
$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
  var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
  var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

  latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
  markerlocations.push(latlng);
});
```

and variations of this with no results.

Would anyone know the correct way of doing this and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `push()` to the array in the `success` handler which has access to the data returned from the request. You would also be better to add objects to the array instead of manually hacking around a JSON string. From there you can pass the array to whatever function you need to execute. Try this:

```
var markerlocations = [];
$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
    var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat; // note 'lat' here, not 'lng'
    var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    markerlocations.push({ lat: lat, lng: lng });
    doSomethingWithTheArray(markerlocations);
});

function doSomethingWithTheArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this too - it makes sense to put the push there, however it's just not working this way either (have added the code I used above).

Comment: Have you checked the network console to ensure the request is working?

Comment: Yes, I can console.log() lat and lng and see the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use foreach to create your array. Then push/append the array as you want.

```
    $.getJSON("url here", function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key, value){

           // your custom code here
           var latlng = 'code you want';

       });
       markerlocations.push(latlng);
   });
```

Comment: This gives me the same error as my code ('latlng' is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an empty array outside getJSON() function. Then it is accessible inside getJSON callback.

```
var markerlocations = [];
$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
    var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    markerlocations.push({ lat: lat, lng: lng });
});
```

function(data)... is the callback function which gets executed once the response is obtained. You don't need another done() method in this case.

```js
var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new york";
var latlng;
var markerlocations = [];
$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
  var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
  var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

  latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
  markerlocations.push(latlng);
  
  // just for testing
  for(var i = 0; i < markerlocations.length; i++){
    alert(markerlocations[i].lat + '===' + markerlocations[i].lng);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, yes there is an empty array declared outside the function. I just didnt include it in my example. I proeviously had exactly what you had here, but it doesnt work

Comment: @MeltingDog are you getting the value of lat and lng correctly?

Comment: @JodyJoseph yes - I can console.log them fine

Comment: @MeltingDog did you add var markerlocations = []; line before getJSON? just to confirm.

Comment: @JodyJoseph, yep it is at the very top

Comment: @MeltingDog please find running script. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101886/discussion-between-joby-joseph-and-meltingdog).